# My webpages div doesnt set dynamic width correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 toolbars, 1 of each side of the screen, and a main content area.  I dont want it to have to sidescroll cause that is pathetic, so i was trying to figure out if someone could help me set it up.

My current attemp was:

```
 $("#main").css("width", window.outerWidth - $("#t1").width() - $("#t2").width());
```

The issue is that it is too big still because of margins.  Instead of me doing width, should i do outerWidth, similar to how i did window, or is there a jquery command which will do just that?

Thanks

here is a basic fiddle:  it is set up differently, but the idea is there.  I just am unsure as to how to do it.  http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/DfZx7/

Upon tinkering deeper and deeper with my fiddle, i am fairly certain i figured it out in the example i had given.  *derp*  Standby while i look and see if i can apply the same thing to my code.

The sample did not work with my code, but border was set to 2px around, for both main and attributes.  Deducting 8 pixels resolves.

Comment: Yes, you can take into account margins with outerWidth `$("#main").css("width", window.outerWidth - $("#t1").outerWidth() - $("#t2").outerWidth());`

Comment: odd. that gives me like 4 pixels difference in the right direction, but i am still sure that i am about 20px off.

Comment: May you set up a fiddle with the full code?

Comment: sure, hold on a second and I will make on

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/DfZx7/

Comment: Could the extra space be due to margin collapsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript to avoid scrollbars. It's a layout width two fixed-width columns and a liquid one.

Here is the "skeleton" of your layout in a responsive way:

```
<div id="window">
    <div id="column-sx"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="column-dx"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#window {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#column-sx {
    width:54px;
    float:left;
}
#column-dx {
    width: 140px;
    float:right;
}
#main {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-194px; /* left + right col width */
}
#main > * {
    margin-right:194px; /* left + right col width */
}
```

This way it will never "break" nor cause an horizontal scrollbar.

Anyway, probably you want to set a `min-width` for #main contents, and add another container for contents instead of targeting them with `> *`

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/JM3gg/) with your code revised

Comment: this works and is a great answer.  In one of the edits I added, there was also an issue with the border widths with the way i was working it.  Your way actually handles that with hardcoded numbers, but it still works.  It also does it in a very simple formatting setup. :)  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome :) anyway, if you're having issues with borders, google "box-sizing:border-box"

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, i would think outerWidth would work. If it doesnt, you can find the margin value via the `.style` attribute - but thats not ideal.

One thing you should be aware of is window resize if your setting your widths dynamically and you truely hate horizontal scrolling. You could put the above function also in the `$().resize()` function to ensure the widths are always within the window and complement this with css `min-width` so it doesnt go too small.

Comment: i am just trying to account for different monitor dimensions.  I didnt want to do the style of the margins, but i think i might, even though as you said, it is not ideal.

Comment: Would .resize() be applicable to an instance where they take the page and remove it from full screen to go to a different monitor for example.  Would that function fire?